# React node not showing up as expected in enzyme test

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I'm on the right path here, but I've reached a point of confusion, and my tests are failing when I would expect them to succeed. I'm trying to write some seemingly straightforward tests for one of my stateless components, and have run into a rut.

Here is the component:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import { Card, CardHeader, CardText } from 'material-ui/Card'
import _ from 'lodash'

import FlashStatsWrapper from './FlashStatsWrapper'

const FlashStats = (props) => (
    <FlashStatsWrapper>
        <Card>
            <CardHeader
                title={`${props.type} FlashStats`}
            />
            <CardText>
                <div className="FlashStats">
                    {_.map(props.stats, (stat, statName) => (
                        <div key={statName}>
                            <span>{statName}: {stat}</span>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </CardText>
        </Card>
    </FlashStatsWrapper>
)

FlashStats.propTypes = {
    type: PropTypes.string,
    stats: PropTypes.object,
}

export default FlashStats
```

Note: 'FlashStatsWrapper' is just a styled-component, a div tag.

And here is the test:

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import { Card, CardHeader, CardText } from 'material-ui/Card'

import FlashStats from '../index'

describe('<FlashStats />', () => {
    it('to be rendered', () => {
        const renderedComponent = shallow(<FlashStats />)
        expect(renderedComponent.find('div.FlashStats').length).toEqual(1)
 })

 it('renders the title', () => {
     const renderedComponent = shallow(<FlashStats type="Users" />)
     expect(renderedComponent.contains(<CardHeader title="Users FlashStats" />)).toBe(true)
 })

 it('parses the stats keys and values', () => {
     const renderedComponent = shallow(<FlashStats stats={{users: 100, advertisers: 30, recurrant: 10, snowflakes: 2}} />)
     //renderedComponent.find('span').tap(n => console.log(n.debug())).map(n => n.props())
     expect(renderedComponent.contains(<span>users: 100</span>)).toBe(true)
     expect(renderedComponent.contains(<span>advertisers: 30</span>)).toBe(true)
     expect(renderedComponent.contains(<span>recurrant: 10</span>)).toBe(true)
     expect(renderedComponent.contains(<span>snowflakes: 2</span>)).toBe(true)
 })
})
```

When I run the test with that debug line, I do see my spans, with the stats as expected inside of them, although they print out a bit differently than I would expect. Interestingly, the 'renders the title' test passes no problem, however the 'parses the stats keys and values' test fails all the way.

Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the docs make pretty clear how shallow vs mount behave differently. I would think that what you are observing is in line withthe docs regarding 'shallow'

Comment: I tried switching to `mount` however I see the exact same behavior, and when I uncomment the debugging line, I see the same output, so I'm not so sure that's it :/